# How do I have an ItemsControl fit its contents and not expand vertically without regard to its sibling elements?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application with layout similar to this defined in the following example XAML:

```
<Window>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="AliceBlue" />

        <!-- Main Panel -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" 
              Background="LightPink">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Row 0: some User Control -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="100" />

            <!-- Row 1: some label -->
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="Example text" />

            <!-- Row 2: another User Control -->
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">

                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl>
                        <ItemsControl.Items>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Item 1" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Item 2" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Item 3" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Item 4" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Item 5" />
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Item 6" />
                        </ItemsControl.Items>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>

                <Button Content="Open" />
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="AliceBlue" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Visually it's intended to look like this:
[image: Application layout]

Simply put, the layout root is a grid that contains 3 columns; the left and right columns are just spacers and the middle column contains 2 User Controls (represented by 2 grids in my above example).

What I am trying to achieve is as follows:

1. If there is enough vertical space, I want the ItemsControl to display no scroll-bar and the button to appear right below the items (not at the bottom of its containing panel).
2. If there isn't enough vertical space, I want the ItemsControl to display a scroll-bar and not expand vertically effectively kicking the button out of view.

A visual example of the desired layout is as in the screenshot below:
[image: Desired layout]

Everything I have tried seems to either:

1. Keep the Open button docked to the bottom when there is plenty of space, or
2. Kick the Open button out of view when there is insufficient space due to the ItemsControl expanding vertically.

Is there any way I can achieve the desired layout (whether it's in XAML or code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the StackPanel by a top-aligned Grid:

```
<!-- Row 2: another User Control -->
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl>
            ...
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Content="Open" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Wouldn't work because if there isn't enough space the ItemsControl would expand vertically attempting to accommodate its items effectively kicking the Open button out of display.

Comment: @AhmedA.Hamid That's not true. You should simply try it before complaining.

Comment: Tried it. It wouldn't kick the Open button out of display but if there is enough space it keeps the button at the bottom which isn't what I am trying to achieve (check visual illustration in the question).

Comment: It doesn't do that for me, so either you didn't try exactly what I've posted, or there is something else you did not show in your question.

Comment: The application I've illustrated in my question was more or less an approximation of the real situation I was running into. It turns out the root cause of the overflow I was seeing was due to some StackPanel laying within a RowDefinition whose Height was set to Auto, which caused the StackPanel to expand well beyond the extents of the main window.

Thank you anyways because your answer helped me find out the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Regardless of your actual problem and its possible solution, this post exactly answers your question. There is no need for saying "thank you anyways" when you haven't shown your real problem. For the future, try to be more specific about your *actual* problems.

Comment: Valuable advice indeed. One posts a technology question and not only does one get an answer but also lessons in life. Much obliged. Thanks again.